# Keeping background process running in Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Not sure how to word this as I am new to Docker, so apologies if this is really basic, or poorly worded.

I used to play on old text-based games back in the day and as an exercise in learning Docker, I want to containerise one of them. The below code is my dockerfile and after some tweaking, I have managed to successfully pull a base image, update it, install dependencies, add a user, extract the game files and perform the install steps. The last part of the process is running the `./restart` command.

When you run this in standard Linux, you can just CTRL+C to return to a prompt while leaving the process running, but something is not right with my container configuration because the container exits as soon as the start-up is complete. What am I missing? I tried running the container with `-it`, but didn't think it would work based on what I know should happen, and it didn't.

```
FROM debian:bookworm-slim
EXPOSE 4201/tcp
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install curl libevent-dev libssl-dev libpcre2-dev build-essential zlib1g-dev -y
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/pennmush/ -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 pennmush
RUN mkdir -p /home/pennmush/pennmush
COPY ./pennmush/ /home/pennmush/pennmush/
RUN chown -R pennmush /home/pennmush
USER pennmush
WORKDIR /home/pennmush/pennmush/
RUN ./configure
RUN make update
RUN make install
WORKDIR /home/pennmush/pennmush/game/
CMD ["./restart"]
```

EDIT: I saw suggestions to add `ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]` to the end of my dockerfile which kept the container alive, though the application server process still exited. But using Portainer, I entered a console and ran the command again, and it is working. So at least I know that the installation was successful, and that this is an issue specifically with how I have configured the image and/or container.

Comment: Docker typically works with processes in the foreground...

Comment: Seems related to the execution of your script and its behavior in a container. If you want to share your game code and could try to debug it on my environment.